# NHibernate change tracking does not pick up changes to a custom type (IUserType)

Tags: nhibernate

I have a model with a `Dictionary<string, string>` property that is stored in the database using JSON. I am using a custom NHibernate type to map the dictionary to and from a JSON-encoded string, which works fine.

My problem is that when I flush the session, and the *only* property that has changed is this dictionary, then the entity is not updated. If any other property has also changed, then the entity (including the JSON string) is updated.

In other words, NHibernate correctly maps the dictionary to JSON using my custom type, but this custom property is NOT used to determine if the entity has changed.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you doing anything interesting in your DeepCopy method? (I *think* this is used in change tracking but not certain).    Can you post your UserType and the primary object's mappings?

Comment: Nope, nothing interesting in DeepCopy, but thanks for the reply. Turns out it was a combination of my Equals() implementation plus some app logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to correctly override `Equals` in your IUserType implementation so that it returns false when it's compared to its initial value. NHibernate uses `Equals` to determine if the field has changes that need to be persisted.

The reason it's updated when another property has changed is that, by default, NHIbernate issues updates including all mapped properties.

Comment: Thanks, my Equals() implementation was the problem... I was returning true if both object references pointed to the same object, and in my application code I was simply modifying the dictionary rather than creating a new one. I think the easiest fix is to change my app to create a new dictionary object when it updates the model.